# How to protect an Office add-in/ prevent an other company to install or use it

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook addin. Installation is simply done by entering the url to the XML manifest file.

I can easily insert this url in different Office accounts, from different Office 365 subscriptions/ companies. If someone would know the url, he can install the add-in.

I'm using Single Sign On to validate if the user is logged in, if logged in he can use the add-in and he will see some data I'm fetching from a web-api.

How to check if this user belongs to the company the add-in was written for and therefore allowed to use the add-in?

I examined the Office JWT token by decoding it, it contains the e-mailadress of the loggedin user and some other fields. Is that the way to check? Or am I missing something here?

The whole purpose of Single Sign On is to prevent an extra login.

Edit: 
I Guess I will go another route after looking at some existing add-in's. I will build my own login, where users are verified in our own backend. Then set a cookie so that they don't have to login every time.

Comment: If you've decided to go another route, please delete the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has updated the question to say, in effect, that it is no longer relevant.